# Come autumn - meaning

Tags: grammar

Source: http://online.wsj.com/articles/many-ukrainians-flee-to-russia-angry-afraid-determined-to-stay-1404333568?ru=yahoo?mod=yahoo_itp

> Many of the summer facilities aren't winterized, so they will have to move **come autumn**, but they don't know where.

Is this just a fancier way of saying **if autumn comes**?

Comment: Yest, it means *when autumn comes* (or *if*, if autumn is not a regular guest in that particular part of the globe). (0:

Comment: @user69786 You got the general idea right, but it's better to understand this *come* as a preposition. See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come_53.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "when autumn comes." (Not "if.")

Checking Google Ngrams, I was surprised by how common 'come [season]' is. 'Come spring' and 'come fall' vastly outnumber 'when ... comes'. 'Come summer' and 'come autumn' outnumber the equivalent and 'when winter comes' is slightly more common than 'come winter'. In each case 'come [season]' has grown in use since about 1900, and 'when [season] comes' has dropped since about 1940. [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come%20autumn%2Cwhen%20autumn%20comes%2Ccome%20winter%2Cwhen%20winter%20comes%2Ccome%20summer%2Cwhen%20summer%20comes%2Ccome%20spring%2Cwhen%20spring%20comes%2Ccome%20fall%2Cwhen%20fall%20comes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20autumn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20autumn%20comes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20winter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20winter%20comes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20summer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20summer%20comes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20spring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20spring%20comes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20fall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20fall%20comes%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: +1 The same pattern is evident with months: 'come April', 'come September'

Comment: This answer contains some great information, and I have upvoted it. But it was flagged as Not An Answer because technically it doesn't answer the question. The OP asks if "come [season]" is another way to say "if [season] comes". If you edit your answer to include something like "*come [season]* is another way of saying ***when*** *[season] comes*", I think it would answer the question quite well.

Answer (score 1):

A weather report on the radio might go like this:
This weekend it will be sunny. Come Monday, there will be a chance of showers and thunderstorms....
When I heard this, I translated it to "This coming Monday..." and similarly, "come autumn" to me simply means "this coming autumn". It's just another way of saying the same thing to avoid repetition, thus giving the language a bit more variety and make it less monotonous. But I'm not sure if it's a fancier way though.